# Modify tag structure of XML and read it

Tags: java, xml

Currently we are making xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE PARTS SYSTEM "parts.dtd">
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="xmlpartsstyle.css"?>
<PARTS>
   <TITLE>Computer Parts</TITLE>
   <PART>
      <ITEM>Motherboard</ITEM>
         </PART>
   </PARTS>
```

But now we want to modify using Java to look as

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE PARTS SYSTEM "parts.dtd">
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="xmlpartsstyle.css"?>
<PARTS>
   <TITLE>Computer Parts</TITLE>
   <PART>
      <ITEM>Motherboard</ITEM>
      <ITEM>Mouse</ITEM> 
      and other parts
    </PART>
</PARTS>
```

This "and other parts" is stored in string and it is to be placed out side item tags and before end of part tag.

I am not able to do it :(
I tried settextContent for node PART but its not working as expected
Also tried setNodevalue also not working

Any help will be appreciated.
TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to create a textnode to hold the "and other parts" bit, then append it as a child node to the PARTS element, just like you append the other elements.  Something like:

```
    Text text = doc.createTextNode("and more parts" );
    parts.appendChild(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your schema should have the `<xs:complexType name="PART" mixed="true">` defined if you are getting troubles in validating your xml file.

Adding the content `<ITEM>Motherboard</ITEM>        <ITEM>Mouse</ITEM>         and other parts`   itself to the PART element can be done by using `createTextNode()` which has the required xml text built into it.